# Is it possible in Oracle APEX to export a table to a file using Automation

Tags: sql, rest, file, oracle-apex

I want to export a table in an Oracle APEX application automatically on a weekly basis to a file. Is there a way to do this without using SQL developer?

Comment: Export to a file where? APEX runs within a browser and requires user interaction to download files to a client workstation. PL/SQL stored procedures running in the database (not really APEX) can be scheduled to run automatically, but will only have access to directories on the database server (assuming UTL_FILE is even available), where end-users would not be able to get the file.

Comment: Essentially I want to download the file to an FTP folder that is shared with another company. I didn't know if apex or their SQL backend had the availability to do that as I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: You *might* be able to use a command-line web client like wget to download the file to the FTP server, but it would depend on your specific APEX application design. Execution of the wget command as a shell script could be scheduled through the client operating system (e.g. cron). Your system and network administrators, and APEX developers should be able to help you with specifics.